# В матрице поменять местами минимум и максимум

Tags: python

Дано матрицу и поменять местами максимум и минимум.Получилось другое ,как исправить помогите:)

```
n=int(input("N:"))
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        a[i].append(int(input("input element:")))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(a[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
maximum = max(a)
minimum = min(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == maximum:
        a[i] = minimum
    elif a[i] == minimum:
        a[i] = maximum
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maximum = max(a)
minimum = min(a)
```

Вы находите ряд в котором наибольшая сумма
найти наибольшее число можно так:

```
maximum = max(max(a, key = lambda line: max(line)))
minimum = min(min(a, key = lambda line: min(line)))
```

в конце вам надо использовать `for` в `for`:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if a[i][j] == maximum:
            a[i][j] = minimum
        elif a[i][j] == minimum:
            a[i][j] = maximum
```

Comment: спасибо большое